# Table Layout broken in IE 10

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, layout, html-table

After loading the table in IE 10, its layout was broken like image following

[image]

After clicking on any cell of the table, all the broken cells were refreshed and displayed correctly.

**HTML**

```
<table class="dxgvTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;empty-cells:show;table-layout:fixed;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;">
<tbody><tr>
    <td style="width:20%;"></td><td style="width:90px;"></td><td style="width:90px;"></td><td style="width:15%;"></td><td style="width:15%;"></td><td style="width:20%;"></td><td style="width:45%;"></td><td style="width:90px;"></td><td style="width:50px;"></td><td></td>
</tr><tr id="ctl00_pageContent_drilldownReport_drilldownReportForm_bucketedCallbackPanel_rptDrilldownBucketed-807be9e3-22b7-4c19-9a06-6cb3ae3c29e7_DXDataRow0" class="dxgvDataRow">
    <td class="dxgv">Deskjet 3510 e-All-in-One Printer</td><td class="dxgv">07/21/2013</td><td class="dxgv">09/30/2013</td><td class="dxgv">Best Buy</td><td class="dxgv">United States</td><td class="dxgv">Easy to use basic printer</td><td class="dxgv">Compact, not too many extras</td><td class="dxgv">PRE</td><td class="dxgv" align="right">1</td><td class="dxgvTable"></td>
</tr><tr id="ctl00_pageContent_drilldownReport_drilldownReportForm_bucketedCallbackPanel_rptDrilldownBucketed-807be9e3-22b7-4c19-9a06-6cb3ae3c29e7_DXDataRow1" class="dxgvDataRow dxgvDataRowAlt">
    <td class="dxgv">Deskjet 3510 e-All-in-One Printer</td><td class="dxgv">07/21/2013</td><td class="dxgv">09/30/2013</td><td class="dxgv">Best Buy</td><td class="dxgv">United States</td><td class="dxgv">Easy to use basic printer</td><td class="dxgv">Document printing is great, color photo quality is also good.</td><td class="dxgv">HWPQ</td><td class="dxgv" align="right">1</td><td class="dxgvTable"></td>
</tr>
```

**CSS**
[image]

Comment: Could you post the related CSS code as well? I believe that will help in getting better responses.

Comment: CSS....................??

Comment: The content in the table is wider than the table itself (115 % + 320 pixels). I'm surprised browsers handle this as well as they do.

Comment: Yes, the problem caused by using both percentage and pixel for columns in table.